# 92 Terrano - Full tank of gas stalls

Tags: fuel-system, nissan, stall

This question is very similar to "Engine hesitates and sometimes stalls after filling gas tank", however seems to be more severe.

I purchased a 92 V-30 (V6) Terrano about a year ago, and have always had this problem. If I fill the gas tank to full, and seal the gas cap, the Terrano will blow a heap of black smoke and if I don't continously apply revs will always stall.

Also after driving for 10-20 minutes, if I get out while it's running and listen around the tank, I can hear a whirring sound (sounds like a pump struggling like crazy).

I've noticed that if I either leave the fuel cap off, or hardly screwed in, it alleviates this problem ever-so-slightly. The pump whirring tends to continue. The truck however never seems to run rough.

To add to this, the previous owner murmured something about replacing the gas tank. I discredited this; I believe (alongside some of the other things he lied about) he made this up because he didn't know what was going on with the tank himself.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Fuel filter change?

Comment: Will check my service papers, I think we had that replaced ~7 months ago and it was still stuttering at full tank but will get back on that